Why vkCreateInstance returns VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED although VULKAN is supported?
My PC supports DirectX11 & Vulkan. I run my unity game with vulkan without problems.

OS: Windows 10
GPU: Nvidia GeForce GT750M

I need to check Vulkan support in a separate C++ project. It is necessary to know about possibility to run my game with vulkan command line arguments.
Here's the code:
bool checkVulkanSupport(VkResult* res) {
    // Initialize Vulkan instance
    VkInstance instance;
    VkInstanceCreateInfo createInfo{};
    createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;

    // Add validation layers
    const char* validationLayers[] = { "VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation" };
    createInfo.enabledLayerCount = 1;
    createInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = validationLayers;

    *res = vkCreateInstance(&createInfo, nullptr, &instance);// << VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED
    // Create a Vulkan instance
    if (*res != VK_SUCCESS)
        return false; // Vulkan instance creation failed

    uint32_t deviceCount = 0;
    vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(instance, &deviceCount, nullptr);

    if (deviceCount == 0) {
        vkDestroyInstance(instance, nullptr);
        return false; // No physical devices found
    }

    std::vector<VkPhysicalDevice> devices(deviceCount);
    vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(instance, &deviceCount, devices.data());

    bool supportsVulkan = false;
    for (const auto& device : devices) {
        VkPhysicalDeviceProperties deviceProperties;
        vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties(device, &deviceProperties);

        // Check if the Vulkan version is at least 1.0.0
        if (deviceProperties.apiVersion >= VK_API_VERSION_1_0) {
            supportsVulkan = true; // Found a Vulkan-supporting device
            break; // No need to check further
        }
    }

    vkDestroyInstance(instance, nullptr); // Clean up Vulkan instance
    return supportsVulkan;
}

I don't know why, but vkCreateInstance returns VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED.
This part of code causes the problem:
// Initialize Vulkan instance
VkInstance instance;
VkInstanceCreateInfo createInfo{};
createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
    
// Add validation layers
const char* validationLayers[] = { "VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation" };
createInfo.enabledLayerCount = 1;
createInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = validationLayers;
    
*res = vkCreateInstance(&createInfo, nullptr, &instance);// << VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED

Why vkCreateInstance returns VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED?

how about a minimal reproducible example? a tag that reflects your os, will also help.

@user14063792468, thank you! I  will send the link on it!

Very likely the CreateInstance call fails due to some parameters you set erroneously, or forgot to specify. Did you try a simple example? https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Setup/Instance

I mean something that has int main(...), compiles and shows your issue is a good place to start. it will be helpful if you could add a make command to compile and run your example.

@user14063792468, here is a simple project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jyjpoqUlV356RHaRLpy_MEpQ_c8yXV41/view?usp=drive_link
Problem appear in checkVulkanSupport(). res  contains VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED and I don't understand the reason of this error.

stackoverflow service wants all code shown here, on SO. make a minimal possible extract of a code that is causing the issue. post it as a code block here, in the body of your question. it will also help to have a makefile, or whichever command you use to compile and link your minimal example. btw, other than outside links are prohibited here, your link requires access grant.

I corrected my question. Still didn't find the reason why vkCreateInstance returns VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED

You should mention the environment, like what OS and GPU as the very minimum.

@Dr. Snoopy, thanks
OS: Windows 10.
GPU: Nvidia GeForce GT750M

Guys, I tried to run Bin/vkcube.exe and got error: "vkCreateInstance Failure. vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties failed to find the VK_KHR_surface extension. Do you have a compatiable Vulcan installable client driver instaled?"  Why this happened? Does it mean my graphic card doesn't support it?

If the only goal is to “check Vulkan support”, then try running vulkaninfo which will give you a lot of information.  Nvidia includes this program in their driver installation, I believe.
If you still need to write a program, your code is acting like it can’t find the validation layer, which is a bit puzzling because you obviously have the Vulkan header files, which are usually obtained from the Vulkan SDK and also contains the validation layer.  If you somehow obtained the headers in some other way, then you need to install the SDK to get the validation layer.

Thank you for answer.
I installed Vulkan SDK in standard way. I need to write a program. All headers are found and the program compiles, but it seems that Vulлan is not supported.
I tried to run: C:\Users\Bob>"F:\Program Files\VulkanSDK\1.3.296.0\Bin32\vulkaninfoSDK.exe"
ERROR at C:\j\msdk0\build\Khronos-Tools\repo\vulkaninfo\vulkaninfo.h:241:vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties failed with ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED
I don't have C:\j\msdk0\build. I Installed SDK in F:\Program Files\Vulkan\

Your GPU is really old and I see some indication that Nvidia placed it in "end of life" status, so it is likely that they dropped support for that GPU in their drivers.  At least all evidence in this post points that way.  You might want to dig around on the Nvidia web site to see if you can find and install an older driver that still supports it

Yeah, the Nvidia manual driver download site suggests that you'll need drivers back from 2018 or 2019 for that GPU.

That message about the "msdk0" path is just the path used by the build machine used to prepare the vulkaninfo binary.  It has nothing to do with your system.
